# Salesforce to Salesforce Record Transfer Limits?

Tags: limits, salesforce2salesforce

Does anyone know of any limits on the number of records (daily) transfered/updated between orgs?

My google foo has failed me and I do not see anything specifically related to this. While I would love to assume there is no limit (would make sense) I do not wish to be incorrect in this case....

Comment: I want to know the same. Do you have any update on this ?

Comment: I have not been able to find any info on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Salesforce to Salesforce is subject to undocumented limits - they arrive suddenly as follows:

> The Salesforce to Salesforce operation from [source] to [target] failed because the Rate limit either in [source] or [target] was exceeded. Error Message : CODE - REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED Message - ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded.. We'll retry the operation in an hour. If more attempts are needed, they'll take place 2, 4, 8, and 16 hours after the previous retry.
>
> Thank you,
>   The Salesforce Team
>
> For more information on how Salesforce to Salesforce impacts existing validation rules and Apex triggers, please refer to the Salesforce help.
>
> [image: S2S rate limits]

It's not clear whether the issue lies on the sending side or the receiving side, as neither org displays anything concerning on its API Limits nor System Overview page. The codified exception type is a new one, seldom spotted in the wild:

https://github.com/koenfaro90/SFDC-ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn-Reproduction